# My keyboard is not working on elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, microsoft-windows, surface-tablet

My built in type cover is not working on Freya (0.3.2) running on the Microsoft Surface Pro 3.But my trackpad works perfectly. Both keyboard and trackpad work when using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Try reporting a bug using the guide that's been linked.